# Guillotine.js: using HTML5 range input for image scaling (zoom in & out)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-guillotine

I am building a website with a feature that allow the users to upload their profile picture. Once the picture is uploaded, a popup will show up so that the user can adjust their profile picture. They're allowed to scale the picture (zoom in & out) and crop it.

To achieve this functionality, I use [guillotine.js](http://guillotine.js.org). The problem is that guillotine uses buttons to zoom in & out. I want to use slider instead of this (like Facebook did when adjusting the profile thumbnail).

I digged out the problem and found this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine/issues/4

Sadly, I can't get the solution above to work.